# Adding items in the nested array of React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects, use-state

I'm trying to add new items to an array of an object that resides in another object of a state. Pretty nested.

So I tried the following way...

```
// The initial data
[options, setOptions] = useState({
    name: 'Name goes here'
    type: 'type goes here'
    series : [{
        type: 'series type',
        label: 'series label'

})
```

Now I want to add another object inside the object of series array with useEffect(). And I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // other functionalities goes here
    setOptions({
        ...options, // for copying previous data outside of series
        series: [{
            ...options.series, //this is for copying previous data of series
            tooltip: {
                enable: true,
        }]
    })
}, [refreshData])
```

The way I'm copying `...options` works absolutely fine, But when I try to copy `...options.series` it adds a new copied object inside the object of series array like the following:

```
{
    name: 'Name goes here' //fine
    type: 'type goes here' //fine
    series: [{
        {type: 'series type', label: 'series label'}, //not fine
        tooltip: {enable: true} //not fine
        //what I want is: to have previous object data and tooltip appended as another item
    }]
}
```

The way I want the object to be is:

```
{
    name: 'Name goes here' //fine
    type: 'type goes here' //fine
    series: [{
        type: 'series type', 
        label: 'series label'
        tooltip: {enable: true}
    }]
}
```

Can Anybody help me regarding this. I would appreciate any help..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is sample of what you are trying to achieve .

```js
const d = {
    name: 'Name goes here',
    type: 'type goes here',
    series : [{
        type: 'series type',
        label: 'series label'
  }]
}


const newD = {
    ...d,
    series: [
        {
          ...d.series[0], // problem is here
          tooltip: {
            enable: true,
          }
        }
      ]
  } 
console.log (newD)
```